# Islamic mythology vs Greek mythology

Tags: atheists, atheism, mythology

So I have been reading some things recently by people like Bill Flavell and others. I
Recently I've been thinking about all the stories about Islam like splitting of the sea, making a stick into a snake etc. What's different between these stories and those of like Greeks they all seem fairytale like. How are these stories of splitting Oceans any different from throwing Lightning bolts etc. If you want to convince someone to believe in these stories it's like trying to believe in the tooth Fairy and so on. What is the difference?

I just find it weird how now that there are more modes of passing evidence even in the prophets time when you could write on pages etc then it was easier to preserve things all these stories have kinda died down. For example the splitting of the moon was seen as more literal but now it's interpreted as an eclipse.

I don't want an answer like "it's all just a test" etc that's not satisfactory.

Comment: Science today has its fairytales too - like the multiverse, simulation, digital physics ...

Comment: And anyway, whats wrong with fairy-tales?

Comment: There's a difference between logical conclusions made by scientists that can very likely exist and parts of which evidently do compared to having sticks turned into snakes. No offence.

Comment: sometimes your logic cannot grasp it because you dont have the exact knowledge about it. after your death, you'll know it InshaAllah.

Comment: So it isn't logical

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes in with how those stories are purported to have happened.

① It makes logical sense that an All Powerful Creator (Allah (ﷻ)) can make anything happen including miracles (splitting of the sea, etc). Even the idea of lightning bolts being thrown around is feasible when One All Powerful God is in the picture; He can make it so Angels are throwing lightning bolts, stars, etc. With Allah (ﷻ), anything is possible. Even mermaids and tooth fairies **could** be real if He wanted them to be.

② Where the Greeks went wrong was in their belief of shirk that there's multiple gods with different powers which is illogical. I pointed out in my blog article "[Disbelief Shattered](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2019/05/12/allahs-%EF%B7%BB-guidance-disbelief-shattered/)" why Mushrikeen (like the Greeks) got it wrong and why other forms of Kufr (disbelief) got it wrong. Basically, powers being broken down among multiple entities and them being harmonious is not logically sound. This is their biggest mistake; once that is understood, their next mistake is not having evidence of their beliefs.

③ Even the facts we know in science (universe arising after a period of nothingness) us are impossible unless there is an All Powerful Creator in the picture.. who existed outside of the Universe, not confined to it. He is the One who set everything into motion and to pretend the universe created itself is a tale just like any other mythical belief.

Comment: For your 3rd points lot of atheist philosophers would say otherwise and also yes an All Powerful God can do that but God does not intervene also having a man who is like 950 years old, splitting a sea and the moon are all things that other nations should've saw but didn't not to mention that all these miracles have stopped happening as soon as there are more means of recording things down or writing them down etc.

Comment: Atheists ‘have' to say otherwise because they need to take God out of the picture to legitimize their view. Like other groups, they are dismissing basic facts. As for your claim that miracles stopped when record keeping started, who do you think started meticulous record keeping (& authentication)? Islam was at the forefront of that. Narrations from different people who saw the split moon are plentiful, including people who never met each other. And except a few, most miracles were localized to the area in which they were done. Most nations were not in the immediate area to see. Common sense!

Comment: Yes but those were all claims from Muslims, not other nations nor is there any impact on the Earth which is just scientifically wrong. Also for saying atheists need to take God out of their picture you are assuming that the re first began with god anyway which is impossible to know and the same thing couldn't be said vice Versa.

Comment: Muslim reports are also historical records. To reject them simply because they are from Muslims is a type of ad hominem fallacy [dismissing an argument based on someone's background rather than the merit of the argument itself]. If God can make a miracle happen, part of that miracle can be "no adverse effects". What we know is that the universe did not exist at one point; either you believe it created itself (epitome of illogic) or you believe it was created by an external source. Not rocket science.